# Segue Opposite Push Effect

Tags: ios, swift, animation, segue, transition

```
VC1 = Table View
VC2 = New VC
```

So I'm using A segue to show VC2 from VC1. When using the segue, VC2 shows coming from the bottom of the screen and covering up VC1. When I go back from VC2 to VC1, VC1 does the same animation.

What I was wondering is, is there any way to reverse the back segue from VC2 to VC1 so either VC2 looks as though it is going downwards or VC1 is coming over it from the top of the screen.

Thanks,
Riley

Comment: Do you have segues for VC1 -> VC2 _and_ VC2 -> VC1 that you both trigger?

Comment: From what I guess: VC1 -- present modally through segue -> VC2, so there is an animation from bottom to up. When you go back to VC1, you should dismiss VC2, but you seem to present modally another VC1, not really coming back. If you show the debug view hierarchy: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html you might see twice VC1 ;)

Comment: I have segues yes from VC1 to VC2 and VC2 to VC1 which are triggered by buttons

Comment: You should dismiss VC2, using `dismiss(animated:completion:)` when button is tapped. No segue needed.

Answer (score 0):

This push effect animation does present modally segue with destination ViewController's transition style *Cover Vertical*

[image]

So when you want to go back from VC 2 to VC 1 with animation opposite to push effect, you can do it just by dismissing VC 2. You don't have to use any segue, just dismiss ViewController.

So from VC 1 you can go to VC 2 by performing segue (you've already done that)

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)
```

[image]

and then from VC 2 you can go back to VC 1 by dismissing VC 2

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]